# xamarin ios build error. Native linking warning: can't parse dwarf compilation unit info

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have created a new xamarin.ios project in VS2013.  Without any changes, I run it on a simulator and it works OK.

Then I change the build target to iPhone and try to run it on my device.  This results in build warnings and taking too long to build, and finally the program runs and exits quickly.

Detailed warnings:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(445,3): warning : Native linking warning: warning: can't parse dwarf compilation unit info in /Users/abolfazl/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/App4/b185777eca505e7ff3e59a8c5a320a44/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/App4.exe.arm64.o
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(445,3): warning : Native linking warning: warning: can't parse dwarf compilation unit info in /Users/abolfazl/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/App4/b185777eca505e7ff3e59a8c5a320a44/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/Xamarin.iOS.dll.arm64.o
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(445,3): warning : Native linking warning: warning: can't parse dwarf compilation unit info in /Users/abolfazl/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/App4/b185777eca505e7ff3e59a8c5a320a44/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/mscorlib.dll.arm64.o
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(445,3): warning : Native linking warning: warning: can't parse dwarf compilation unit info in /Users/abolfazl/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/App4/b185777eca505e7ff3e59a8c5a320a44/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/App4.exe.armv7.o
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(445,3): warning : Native linking warning: warning: can't parse dwarf compilation unit info in /Users/abolfazl/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/App4/b185777eca505e7ff3e59a8c5a320a44/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/Xamarin.iOS.dll.armv7.o
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(445,3): warning : Native linking warning: warning: can't parse dwarf compilation unit info in /Users/abolfazl/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/App4/b185777eca505e7ff3e59a8c5a320a44/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/mscorlib.dll.armv7.o
```

VS:VS2013 update 4

xamarin extenstion for vs: 3.9.236

xamarin ios:8.6.0.51

xamarin build host:3.9.0.234

xcoode:6.1

Win: 8.1 x64

Mac:10.10 os

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a problem with version.
I update to new release. fix it